# Override and Change the middle of a function Odoo

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-12

I would like to override a function called **_cart_update** which is in the **website_sale** module. But I want to change the middle of the function (I want to do something in the middle of the function code). So I tried to rewrite the function in my custom module and add the **website_sale** module as a dependency module (I rewrite the function without adding any **super()** calls). My function gets the function call. No problem with that. But there are other modules that override the same function with **super()** calls. Sadly, those functions will not be executed. But I want them to be executed.

Is there any issue with my work? or is there any other way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a **monkey patching**:

```py
from odoo.addons import website_sale  # so we can update the method in the class
# import any global variable that the method use directly from of website_sale
# I think I covered all variable but in version 11, I don't know if they change it in 12
from odoo.addons.website_sale.models.sale_order import _logger, ValidationError, request, UserError, _, api
# import any thing you need to use in your custom code if there is

@api.multi
def _cart_update(self, product_id=None, line_id=None, add_qty=0, set_qty=0, attributes=None, **kwargs):
    # put the full code here
    # you don't need to call super because it will be the last one to call
    # it's like we defined it in the website_sale 

# at the end replace the method in the class that was defined in the website_sale
website_sale.models.SaleOrder._cart_update = _cart_update
```

The only solution is to replace the method in the **class** because if you use `super` in one of the `sub classes` the original method will be `executed`.